# android date keyboard type for EditText

Tags: android

I want to set a this custom keyboard for and EditText
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

and this for another

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE);
```

but both `EditText` keyboards looks the same.

I want a keyboard for date and another custom keyboard for email but both keyboards looks the same like an usual keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for the email `EditText` is

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
                            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

and for the date `EditText` is:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_NORMAL)
```